# c++ udp server doesn't receive packets

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, 3dsmax

I've written a UDP receiver in C++ with a Java client.

The client's receiver IP (C++ server) is set like `192.168.1.xxx` as server and client are in a private network on different devices.

Everything works just fine.

On another hand. I have a 3ds Max plugin which forks a thread to do some async stuff. The problem is when I run the mentioned C++ server code in that thread, it receives nothing.

Does the thread run in a local environment that can't access `192.168.1.xxx`?

**maxsdk C++ part**

```
void InitWinsock()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
}

void update_state(Interface* ip)
{
    SOCKET socketS;

    InitWinsock();
    struct sockaddr_in local;
    struct sockaddr_in from;
    int fromlen = sizeof(from);
    local.sin_family = AF_INET;
    local.sin_port = htons(12345);
    local.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.106");

    socketS = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    bind(socketS, (sockaddr*)&local, sizeof(local));
    char buffer[1024];
    while (1)
    {
        ZeroMemory(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

        if (recvfrom(socketS, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (sockaddr*)&from, &fromlen) != SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("Received message from %s: %s\n", inet_ntoa(from.sin_addr), buffer);
            ip->PushPrompt((wchar_t*)buffer);
            //sendto(socketS, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (sockaddr*)&from,    fromlen);
        }

        Sleep(50);
    }
    closesocket(socketS);

    return;
}

void PCamMaxPlugin::BeginEditParams(Interface* ip,IUtil* iu) 
{
    this->iu = iu;
    hPanel = ip->AddRollupPage(
        hInstance,
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_PANEL),
        DlgProc,
        GetString(IDS_PARAMS),
        0);
    thread (update_state, ip).detach();
    ip->PushPrompt(_M("----"));
}
```

**C++ udp server**

```
#include <winsock.h>
#include <cstdio>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

void InitWinsock()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
}

int main()
{
    SOCKET socketS;

    InitWinsock();
    struct sockaddr_in local;
    struct sockaddr_in from;
    int fromlen = sizeof(from);
    local.sin_family = AF_INET;
    local.sin_port = htons(12345);
    local.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.106");

    socketS = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    bind(socketS, (sockaddr*)&local, sizeof(local));
    char buffer[1024];
    while (1)
    {
        ZeroMemory(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (recvfrom(socketS, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (sockaddr*)&from, &fromlen) != SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("Received message from %s: %s\n", inet_ntoa(from.sin_addr), buffer);
            //sendto(socketS, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (sockaddr*)&from, fromlen);
        }
        Sleep(50);
    }
    closesocket(socketS);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use `netstat` to check whether the UDP port is still opened after the server code was moved.

Comment: @LWimsey I'll check it out. thanks

Comment: @user4581301 you're right. I edited the post to avoid more downvotes. Thank you

Comment: Note, after `recvfrom()` exits, your `printf` and `PushPrompt` calls assume the `buffer` is null-terminated, but that is not guaranteed. You need to take the return value of `recvfrom()` into account to know how much of the `buffer` has been filled. Also, your 3DS code should NOT be calling `WSAStartup()` on every new thread created. Ideally it should be called only once, such as at app startup, or at least when the plugin is loaded. But, if you do call it in every thread, then you need to call `WSACleanup()` before the thread exits.

Comment: So why it works fine as a separate program? In 3Ds code ```recvfrom``` always return ```SOCKET_ERROR```. And your mentioned issue will come up only if the plugin is going to get loaded twice or more since it sees the requested port is busy. But basically, it must work once.

Comment: @A_Kz: if this question is still valid, have you adjusted firewall rules for 3dsmax.exe?